# importXML Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I find lots of examples importing XML into a Google Sheet that starts with HTML code.  I'm having problems extracting data from XML that has no styling information.

This is the URL

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20return.last.value%20from%20json%0AWHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fmtgox.com%2Fapi%2F1%2FBTCUSD%2Fticker'&diagnostics=true

I've tried many options including what I think is the full path, but Google complains about a bad XPath

```
 =ImportXML("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20return.last.value%20from%20json%0AWHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fmtgox.com%2Fapi%2F1%2FBTCUSD%2Fticker'&diagnostics=true","/results/json/restun/last/value")
```

Comment: Not sure, but why not try to use prefix the XPath with an extra slash: "//results/json/restun/last/value"? Because, as I can see, 'results' is not the root node. Using '//' at the beginning of XPath will instruct to search starting not from the root node, but from any node in the document.

Comment: When I use this it says, "error: The data could not be parsed. Please make sure the URL points to valid XML or HTML."

It sure looks like valid XML to me.

Comment: Since what you need is the text from the 'value' tag, try the following XPath: "//results/json/restun/last/value/text()"

Comment: Same error.  I setup a sheet with the formula in it if you want to see what it's doing.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdGhETzM4dllHSmxiaUZ2allJbVhDZFE&usp=sharing

Comment: Found [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Q4puETL12g4) the description of the problem you are probably encountering. "The ImportXML function in Google Docs spreadsheet can not process data that is created in a two-step process. I.e. when the URL tells the server to dynamically create an xml output after which the user is redirected to this ouput - even when the URL stays the same." The thread is quite old and I don't know if this problem is still there.

Comment: There were two guys that cracked the code, so to speak, or at least came up with workable solutions to accomplish what I was asking here.  They didn't necessarily figure this out exactly how I was asking.  You bitcoin and Google Sheet fans can go here to see their solutions. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/chrome-browser/-uGQs2sQaIk